# Android Studio cant find a resource with a given name

Tags: android

I am making my first app using Android Studios tutorial and I keep on having this error every time I try to make it. The error is No resource found that matches the given name (at 'hint' with value '@string/edit_message'). This is my code. In one xml file.

```
<    ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?   >

<    LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width= "match_parent"

    android:layout_height= "match_parent"

    android:orientation=   "horizontal"  >

    <   EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"

        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:layout_width="0dp"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:hint=**"@string/edit_message" />**

    <  Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text=**"@string/button_send"** />

< /LinearLayout>
```

Then in another xml file i have this.

```
<  ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<  resources>

    < string name="app_name">My first app second try</string>

    < string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>

    < string name="action_settings">Settings</string>


    < resources>
        < string name="app_name">My First App</string>

        < string name=**"edit_message">Enter a message</string>**

        < string name=**"button_send">Send</string>**

        < string name="action_settings">Settings</string>

        < string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>

    </resources>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your `string.xml` as this, removing the second `resources` tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>

    <string name="app_name">My first app second try</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="app_name_2">My First App</string>
    <string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
    <string name="button_send">Send</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>

</resources>
```

If you read [String Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) android document, you'll get the whole gist.

Comment: i did what you wrote and then when I ran the program again two more errors came. One was "cannot find symbol variable container" which when i clicked on led me to a file that i had not changed at all. The code for it is; if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit(); the Second error is Execution failed for task ':My first app Second Try:compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details. Shobhit Puri

Comment: It isn't related to the above error of yours. That seems to be a different one altogether. post stacktrace place

Comment: in your layout file, there is no elemts with `container` as id.

Answer (score 0):

You've got two opening `<resources>` tags. Remove the inner tags.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>

    <string name="app_name">My first app second try</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="app_name">My First App</string>
    <string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
    <string name="button_send">Send</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>

</resources>
```